# Is there any way to reduce execution time of Radius outlier removal [pcl outlier removal]?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, vision

Now I work in Point Cloud, in my case, my Point Cloud is noisy in outlier,  I want to clear the noise, so I go with the Radius outlier filter in PCL. The execution time of small clouds is good, but the time will increase as the point cloud size increases.

```
pcl::RadiusOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZ> outrem;
 outrem.setInputCloud(box_cloud);
outrem.setRadiusSearch(0.007);
outrem.setMinNeighborsInRadius (150);
outrem.setKeepOrganized(false);
// apply filter
outrem.filter (*box_cloud);**
```

In my case, it takes around 15 seconds.

Looking for a solution to reduce this time.

Answer (score 1):

[pcl::RadiusOutlierRemoval](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_radius_outlier_removal.html)

> Iterates through the entire input once, and for each point, retrieves the number of neighbors within a certain radius.

So the runtime depends on the number of points in the cloud, and the search radius (the larger the radius, the slower the tree queries will be).

Possible approaches:

1. If some points are definitely not outliers, you can exclude them using: [setIndices()](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_p_c_l_base.html#ab219359de6eb34c9d51e2e976dd1a0d1). For example, if you know that all your outliers have dark color (intensity < I), than you can pre-select all indices of points with `intensity < I` using [pcl::PassThrough](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_pass_through.html).
2. Reduce search radius (and min neighbors accordingly).
3. I believe the algorithm isn't parallelized internally. So you can split the work across multiple threads, each removing outliers from a subset of the cloud. Note that the division should be spatial and not based on indices - [`pcl::CropBox`](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_crop_box.html) may be used for this.
4. "**Approximated** Radius Removal" can be achieved using [pcl::OctreePointCloud](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1octree_1_1_octree_point_cloud.html) by iterating leaf voxel and counting number of points within a voxel (if a voxel contains less than X points, then all points in voxel should be removed).